# singularity of total transform

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}k[x,y,z,w]/(xw-yz)\subset Y=\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y,z,w]$. Let $\tilde{Y}:=\operatorname{Blow}_P Y$, where $P$ is the origin. The exceptional divisor is $E$.
Is the total transform of $X$ a variety with only double normal crossing singularity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to see in coordinates. $\tilde{Y}$ in this scenario can be written as the vanishing of all $2\times 2$ minors of

$
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y & z & q \\
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3\end{bmatrix}
$

in $\mathbb{A}^4\times\mathbb{P}^3$. Then for example in the coordinate neighborhood $a_0=1$ we have that the support of the total transform of $X$ can be written as $x\cdot ( a_3-a_2 a_3)$, giving us the normal crossing (if we are not just considering the support then clearly the exceptional is non-reduced which prevents normal crossing).

Comment: i got $x^2\cdot (a_3-a_2\cdot a_3)$....because its a degree 2 equation....so i got total transform is non-reduced

Comment: Sorry for some reason I took you to mean the support of the total transform because otherwise it is obviously not a normal crossing divisor. I will edit my answer.